# Programmatic RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to programmatically add several Tiles which extend from `TextViews` into a `RelativeLayout`.

My code is as follows.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    Tile tile = new Tile(this);
    tile.setText(Character.toString(characters[i]));
    tile.setId(i);
    if (i != 0) {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i - 1);
    }
    _display.addView(tile, params);
}
```

So I'm creating a new instance class of `LayoutParams` called `params` and adding a rule to align each tile to the right of the previous tile. When I run the app it appears that the tiles are overlapping over each other. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reuse the same LayoutParams object for every view. You need to create a new one every time.